# MySQL IF Time Conversion

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am looking for a way to do something, I have never done before.

I have the Query as

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(pi.start,'+00:00','+10:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') as start,
ifnull(dc.name,'Unknown') as source,
format(sum(ifnull(pi.rev,0)),2) as revenue
from trk.provider_imp pi
left outer join trk.dsp_client dc
on pi.clientid = dc.id
and type = 'client'
where pi.start between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 5  MONTH) AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-%d')
and pi.status = 1
group by start,pi.clientid
order by pi.start, pi.clientid;
```

The above query works and I get the results that I desire, however, for the Time Zone Conversion, I am an hour behind, for Nov, Dec and Jan.

Is there a way where I could add a if statement, and that would do something like, if 'start' is in ('Nov 2014','Dec 2014', 'Jan 2015', than 'start' plus one hour)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you need, the simplest and most effective way I have found was to use your actual location as a parameter, and not the GMT offset.

For instance, if you are in Melbourne, instead of using '+10:00' in Winter and '+11:00' in Summer, you would simply mention 'Australia/Melbourne' in the timezone parameter. Doing this will take care of the daylight savings time offset.

Your example mentioned +10, I'm assuming Melbourne; these 2 statements will return different times as the DST offset is different:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2015-01-01 02:00:00','UTC','Australia/Melbourne');
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2015-10-01 02:00:00','UTC','Australia/Melbourne');
```

The caveat is that standard MySQL installations do not come with the timezone names built-in.
Follow these instructions to get those in your MySQL server: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html